# storing a string via. Entry - Tkinter/Python

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm creating a program that helps solve quadratic equations - this is only an outcast to the layout, but essentially when I input the parameters (`A`, `B` and `C`) it should store it and then I can use it later.

this is what I got so far (Don't mind the names and text, it's in danish):

```
Vara = StringVar()
Varb = StringVar()
Varc = StringVar()

#Parabel
def Parabel():

    parabel = Tk()
    parabel.minsize(600, 400)
    parabel.maxsize(600,400)
    parabel.title("Parablens rødder")

    pLabel = Label(parabel, text = "Parablens rødder").pack(side = TOP)
    pLabel1 = Label(parabel, text = "Indtast parameterne A, B, C:").pack()
    #A
    pLabel2 = Label(parabel, text = "A:").pack()
    pEntry1 = Entry(parabel, textvariable = Vara).pack()
    #B
    pLabel3 = Label(parabel, text = "B:").pack()
    pEntry2 = Entry(parabel, textvariable = Varb).pack()
    #C
    pLabel4 = Label(parabel, text = "C:").pack()
    pEntry3 = Entry(parabel, textvariable = Varc).pack()

    pButton = Button(parabel, text = "OK", command = para ).pack()


def para():
    a = Vara.get()
    b = Varb.get()
    c = Varc.get()

    print(a,b,c) # just to test if they got stored,
```

From what I've read about this should work, but when I print a,b,c it comes up blank.

Answer (score 1):

If this is the complete program, then it has a few problems. On my PC it didn't run at all (no GUI, exceptions), maybe you can run it, but it won't do anything logical. This is why:

1) You can't create StringVar before calling `Tk()`. In my code (trying to fix yours) I added two lines at the very beginning:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
```

2) You didn't activate the Tkinter's main loop. I added this line at the bottom of Parabel():

```
root.mainloop()
```

3) I added a line calling to your function:

```
Parabel()
```

And I got it running Ok.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention, this is only a cutout of the program.
I can send you the full program if that helps?
Thank you for responding.